# How to post images with text in facebook integration in Iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

Here Iam having a problem.Actually I implemented the facebook integration in my application and I need to post the images with text but I dont have any idea how to work on this.can anyone suggest this with a sample code so that it is very helpful for me.

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Comment: guys please give me a prompt solution for this.

Comment: Do you mean you want to upload the images which contain text, or publish a Facebook stream with a title, caption and an image?

Comment: I want to publish the image with a title caption and image.but I want to post the images stored in my database not a link can u suggest anymore for this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want to draw some text in an image, and then upload the image to Facebook.

At first, we need to draw the original image and the desired text into a new image.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320.0, 320.0));
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
// Draw the original image
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, 320.0)];
// Draw the text
[@"text" drawInRect:CGRectMake(...) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

And then, convert the image into NSData and call Facebook's "photos.upload" API to upload it.

```
NSMutableDictionary *args = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
[args setObject:@"caption" forKey:@"caption"];      
FBRequest *uploadPhotoRequest = [FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self];
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);
[uploadPhotoRequest call:@"photos.upload" params:args dataParam:data];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upload the images to your server, and post a small story to Facebook's wall. Use the stream API.

```
FBStreamDialog *dialog = [[[FBStreamDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
dialog.delegate = self;
dialog.userMessagePrompt = @"Prompt";

NSString *name = @"Your caption";
NSString *src = @"http://example.com/path/of/your/image";
NSString *href = @"http://what/happens/if/the/user/click/on/the/image";

NSString *attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"%@\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\", \"src\":\"%@\", \"href\":\"%@\"}]}", name, src, href];
dialog.attachment = attachment;
[dialog show];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would be happy using [BMSocialShare](http://github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare). It's a simple lib I wrote.

```
BMFacebookPost *post = [[BMFacebookPost alloc] 
                        initWithTitle:@"Simple sharing via Facebook, Email and Twitter for iOS!" 
                        descriptionText:@"Posting to Facebook, Twitter and Email made dead simple on iOS. Simply include BMSocialShare as a framework and you are ready to go." 
                        andHref:@"https://github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare"];    

[post setImageUrl:@"http://www.blockhausmedien.at/images/logo-new.gif" 
         withHref:@"http://www.blockhaus-media.com"];

[[BMSocialShare sharedInstance] facebookPublish:post];
```